# How to add multiple properties to a CollectionViewGroup?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm looking for a way to add multiple properties on a `CollectionViewGroup`, actually I defined two `CollectionViewGroup`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Collections}" x:Key="GroupedItems">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" />
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Surname" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

so in my `DataGrid` I've this implementation

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        some columns
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <GroupStyle>
       ...
    </GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
       ...
    </GroupStyle>
 </DataGrid>
```

now in my second Group I want also group for another property called `Number`, so I should get this visualization:

```
Name                 <--Items grouping
   Surname
      Number 1
      Number 2 
      Number 3
```

is possible do that? 'cause I can set only a `PropertyName` for each group, thanks.

Comment: you wont ONLY your second group to from a group inside based on "Number"? why cant you simply add another PropertyGroupDescription for "Number"?

Comment: yep, I need two property binding on the second group such as surname and number, I doesn't want create another grouping for the number that's why